# Hemingway English

Tags: syntax, subjects, predicate

I have no issues with the book (A Farewell to Arms), it's so far generally easy to read, but sometimes I stumble across weird sentences like this one:

> Suddenly to care very much and to sleep to wake with it sometimes morning and all that had been there gone and everything sharp and hard and clear and sometimes a dispute about the cost.

What is this? Where's the subject, where's the predicate? I can't grasp the syntax of it.

Comment: It is not a sentence, but a rambling series of thoughts. It has no subject or predicate. Without further context, it's hard to know what it's about other than haphazard reflections on life.

Comment: Hemingway is not an easy author to read.  He often played very fast and loose with syntax, favoring a kind of stream-of-consciousness style.

Comment: @stangdon Wells was harder (a lot of literary and outdated words and expressions). Here, I hardly ever check a dictionary

Comment: Hemingway's words are mostly simple enough but, as stangdon said, he sometimes uses a stream-of-consciousness style.